# Visual Studio 2013 Diff Window with 3rd Party Source Control

Tags: visual-studio, surroundscm

I really like the Diff tool that they added in Visual Studio 2013. At work we use a 3rd party source control provider (Surround SCM). Is there a way to configure 3rd party source control provider to use Visual Studio's Diff tool?

Comment: Vsdiffmerge.exe is the tool and can be used independently of VS2013. Just point your source control to that exe if it has the capability to configure the diff tool. Any source control worth using will have that feature.

Comment: That's the one I was looking for, thanks! I got it to work for comparing a checked out file with Surround though it doesn't seem to want to compare a non-checked out file. If I'm able to find the correct configuration to do this, I'll post an update. Thanks again!